# "Courtesy [was] extended" - how does adding or removing "was" affect the meaning?

Tags: grammar

> The meeting was not an obligation, but a courtesy *extended* by both parties.

Is this sentence correct?
I think "was extended.." in place of "extended" will fit.

Comment: You could insert "that was" to maintain the sense of the original (the meeting _was_ the courtesy), but inserting "was" alone conveys something completely different (the courtesy can now refer to something other than the meeting).

Comment: I've edited your question's title to make it more descriptive. Please feel free to roll back the edit or change it further if it isn't suitable.